# Almacenar Log de errores y debug para django

Tags: python, django

espero puedan ayudarme, estoy usando este código para almacenar el log de mi aplicación con django 1.10 pero me continua generando el log de un tamaño grande (mas de 200mb y aumentando), me gustaría saber como hacerle para que genere un archivo mas pequeño y y si es posible que se vaya sobreescribiendo, y si es posible poner en un archivo los DEBUG y en otro los ERROR. Gracias.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/elros/logs/debug.log',
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*16,
        'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Al parecer tu problema se soluciona utilizando la opción

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Tal como lo recomiendan [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682413/django-rotating-file-handler-stuck-when-file-is-equal-to-maxbytes) y [aquí](http://azaleasays.com/2014/05/01/django-logging-with-rotatingfilehandler-error/)

Es un problema de hilos y al parecer el servidor de desarrollo no se pone de acuerdo cuando parar/seguir escribiendo en el archivo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, en este caso mi aplicación corre mediante gunicorn y no por el servidor de desarrollo y me ha generado logs hasta de 300mb.

Comment: como seria para ese caso?